# node_modules removal on Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, angular6, node-modules

We have an Angular 6 project which contains approximately 660 MB of packages in the node_modules folder. Since the project's inception, upon building the project we would remove the entire node_modules folder and then perform an npm install to re-download and install all of the packages found in `package.json`.

However, the build times have increased to 15 - 20 minutes. If we comment out the command to remove that folder the build time is between 3 - 4 minutes. What are we gaining to always have a brand new download of the defined packages?